# IronPython Spotfre: Set Listbox Filter Values from user input of Table Name

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I am new to ironPython Scripting and I am trying the do the following.

I page in Spotfire and I created a document property input field and a listbox filter

All I am trying to do is, based on the table name given in get the listbox filter to unque values of a column of the selected table.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import ListBoxFilter

# Get the input variable select_table (assuming it's a Document Property)
select_table = Document.Properties["select_table"]

# Get the ListBox filter named "ReFC.WellList"
well_list_filter = None
for filter in Document.FilteringSchemes:
    if filter.Title == "ReFC.WellList" and isinstance(filter, ListBoxFilter):
        well_list_filter = filter
        break

# Check if the ListBox filter was found
if well_list_filter is not None:
    # Clear existing values from the ListBox filter
    well_list_filter.Reset()

    # Determine which table to use based on the selection
    if select_table == "A":
        table = Document.Data.Tables["Table A"]
        column_name = "Well"  # Assuming the column name in Table A is "Well"
    elif select_table == "B":
        table = Document.Data.Tables["Table B"]
        column_name = "Well"  # Assuming the column name in Table B is "Well"
    else:
        print("Invalid selection")

    # Get unique values from the selected table column
    unique_values = set(row[column_name] for row in table.GetRows())

    # Add the unique values to the ListBox filter
    well_list_filter.SetSelection(unique_values)

    # Optionally, select all values in the ListBox filter
    well_list_filter.IncludeAllValues = True

else:
    print("ListBox filter 'ReFC.WellList' not found")
```

it doesnt seem to be working.. Any idea where I am going wrong?